# Declaring variables in handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

Please see the code below :

```
{{#if abc}}
  <floating-label-select>
     <label for="123" class="456">
         {{#if def}}
             {{xy}}
         {{else}}
             {{yz}}
         {{/if}}
     </label> 
 </floating-label-select>


{{else}}
  <floating-label-select default-value>
      <label for="123" class="456">
         {{#if def}}
             {{xy}}
         {{else}}
             {{yz}}
         {{/if}}

  </floating-label-select>

{{/if}}
```

If you noticed, this part is common in If and else

```
         {{#if def}}
             {{xy}}
         {{else}}
             {{yz}}
         {{/if}}
```

How can I put the value in variable and use that variable instead of having if else at multiple places.

I figured that we have three ways :

1. partials, but getting the error 
   The partial mypartial could not be found
2. Also I tried using register helper 
   Got some error with this too.
3. Creating a separate function (not willing to do that ways)

Please suggest if you know the simpler way or help me with the 2nd option.

Thanks

Comment: It all depends on your data. What is your data structure? What key/value pairs are you sending?

Comment: data structure for what ? ` xy ` and ` yz ` would be simply strings.
I would fetch these values from some file which is fetched dynamically.